# OpenGL simple triangle_strip rendering

Tags: android, opengl, andengine, vbo

I have question to mesh drawed by triangle_strip and line_strip with AndEngine.

I'm generating 2d terrain using triangle_strip , triangles are created this way

```
    1  3
    |\ |\
    | \| \
    0  2  4


    final int pSegmentsCount    = 51;                       
    final int pVertexCount      = ( Mesh.VERTEX_SIZE * (pSegmentsCount) );  
    final float pColor          = new Color(0f,0f,0f).getABGRPackedFloat();
    final float pSegmentWidth   = ( CAMERA_WIDTH/pSegmentsCount );

    float[] pBufferData = new float[pVertexCount];      
    mHeightOffsetCurrent = new float[pVertexCount];     
    float x = 0f,y = 0f;
    for (int i = 0;i<(pSegmentsCount);i++){
        if (i%2!=0) { //every 3rd point goes up 2-4-6 , 0-1-3-5 stays down at 0 , x increments every third point
            y = 200;
        } else {
            x = pSegmentWidth*i; //step right by segment
            y = 0;
        }
        mHeightOffsetCurrent[i] = 0; //init default offset 
        pBufferData[(i * Mesh.VERTEX_SIZE) + Mesh.VERTEX_INDEX_X] = x;
        pBufferData[(i * Mesh.VERTEX_SIZE) + Mesh.VERTEX_INDEX_Y] = y;
        pBufferData[(i * Mesh.VERTEX_SIZE) + Mesh.COLOR_INDEX] = pColor;
    }
    pBufferData[((pSegmentsCount-1) * Mesh.VERTEX_SIZE) + Mesh.VERTEX_INDEX_Y] = -300;

    final VertexBufferObjectManager VBOM = getVertexBufferObjectManager();
    final HighPerformanceMeshVertexBufferObject pMeshVBO = new HighPerformanceMeshVertexBufferObject(VBOM, pBufferData, pVertexCount, DrawType.DYNAMIC, true, Mesh.VERTEXBUFFEROBJECTATTRIBUTES_DEFAULT);
    pMesh = new Mesh(0, 0,pVertexCount,DrawMode.LINE_STRIP,pMeshVBO);
```

i'm changing last vertex y position to better illustrate it

here is what i get ,

line_strip
[image]

triangle_strip
[image]

when i set Y of the last point to 0 i still see line with gradient to starting point.

What i'm doing wrong ? Why the last element is connected with the first one and how to fix this? 
Arrays are drawed by glDrawArrays.

```
public static final int VERTEX_INDEX_X = 0;
public static final int VERTEX_INDEX_Y = Mesh.VERTEX_INDEX_X + 1;
public static final int COLOR_INDEX = Mesh.VERTEX_INDEX_Y + 1;
public static final int VERTEX_SIZE = 2 + 1;
```

Comment: Could you tell me what the actual values for Mesh.VERTEX_SIZE, Mesh.VERTEX_INDEX_X, Mesh.VERTEX_INDEX_Y, and Mesh.COLOR_INDEX are?

Comment: updated in question, indexes 0,1,2, size 3 ( X + Y + COLOR )

Comment: With `GL_LINE_STRIP` last segment shouldn't be connected to the first one. Bug in that "andengine", whatever that is?

Comment: Could you provide your call to glDrawArrays()?

Comment: Is the Mesh class something you wrote, or is it part of andengine?

Comment: It is part of andengine  link : https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2-AnchorCenter/src/org/andengine/entity/primitive/Mesh.java 

GLES20.glDrawArrays(pPrimitiveType, 0, pVertexCountToDraw);

Comment: Is pVertexCountToDraw == pVertexCount and pPrimitiveType == GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP (or GL_LINE_STRIP)?

Comment: Yes. Additionaly all data is passed throught vbo -> https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2-AnchorCenter/src/org/andengine/entity/primitive/vbo/HighPerformanceMeshVertexBufferObject.java

Comment: I'm sorry, I've been looking at this for awhile now, but I can't figure it out. The thing that I thought was weird, was that there is a gradient at all. If the last vertex was really connected to the first, I would think that the triangle would be solid black, since that is the color of the last and first vertex.

Comment: What happens if you pass pSegmentsCount instead of pVertexCount when creating pMeshVBO? And you do the same when you create pMesh?

Comment: Result is exactly the same, even if i change this parameter to some stupid value like -1,5 etc  it still display like above...., well i traced this deeper and i found this : super(pVertexBufferObjectManager, pBufferData.length, pDrawType, pAutoDispose, pVertexBufferObjectAttributes); in HighPerformanceVertexBufferObject

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24406/discussion-between-bwroga-and-pawel-p)